# Error when checking input: expected input_32 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (1000, 12)

Tags: python-3.x, keras

i have the following problem. By implementing the following code

```
def model(inp_size):
    inp = Input(shape=(inp_size, 1))

    x1 = Dense(50, activation='elu')(inp)
    x1 = Dense(20, activation='elu')(x1)
    x1 = Dense(1, activation = 'linear')(x1)

    x2 = Dense(50, activation='elu')(inp)
    x2 = Dense(20, activation='elu')(x2)
    x2 = Dense(1, activation = 'linear')(x2)

    x3 = Dense(50, activation='elu')(inp)
    x3 = Dense(20, activation='elu')(x3)
    x3 = Dense(1, activation = 'linear')(x3)

    x4 = Dense(50, activation='elu')(inp)
    x4 = Dense(20, activation='elu')(x4)
    x4 = Dense(1, activation = 'linear')(x4)



    x1 = Lambda(lambda x: x * 3)(x1)
    x2 = Lambda(lambda x: x * 2)(x2)
    x3 = Lambda(lambda x: x * 2)(x3)
    x4 = Lambda(lambda x: x * 1)(x4)

    out = Add()([x1, x2, x3, x4])

    return Model(inputs = inp, outputs = out)

X_train = np.random.rand(1000,12)
y_train =np.random.rand(1000,1)
NN_model = model(X_train.shape[1])
NN_model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error', optimizer='Adamax', metrics=['mean_absolute_error'])
#N_model.summary()
NN_model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10,verbose = 1)
predictions = NN_model.predict(X_test)



print('NN MAE = ', MAE)
```

I get the error

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_34 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (1000, 12)
```

Which i dont get, as i thought i defined the input layer as inp = Input(shape=(inp_size, 1)) which should be 1000, 1 for each data set

Sorry if this is a very naive question , i am still a beginner
Thanks!

Comment: Change `inp = Input(shape=(inp_size,1))` to `inp = Input(shape=(inp_size,))`.

Comment: Did this and got
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer dense_13: expected min_ndim=2, found ndim=1

Comment: Which line did this error occur?

Comment: ---> 31     x1 = Dense(50, activation='elu')((inp))

This one

Comment: It worked!! I forgot i had changed the code somewhat. Thanks!!!